# What should be sent as parameters to XCORR in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, time, alignment, mp3

We have used audioread to read 2 different .MP3 files as following:

```
[Y1, s1] = audioread('super_mario.mp3');
```

Results are Y1 is an Nx2 vector and S1 is a double number.

The goal is to find a time difference between audio files and align them.
We used xcorr on this purpose like this xcorr (A,B).

Xcorr takes 2 Nx1 and Nx1 vectors and finds cross correlation between them, but we obtain an Nx2 vector and a number.

The question is what we should send to xcorr as parameters?

Comment: You got stereo audio. You can start by comparing one channel from each audio signal. Pick say first column in Y1 for both audio files and try finding time alignment.

Comment: But can't it decrease the accuracy of the result depending on which column we choose? @Navan

Comment: And which raw do we have to select from Nx2 matrix? @Navan

Comment: As I mentioned I would start with first column of Nx2 matrix. Once you have this working you can look into improving accuracy by using data from other channels. But the method would be same.